# How to create a Matlab symbol composition ∆t?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'd like to create a single symbol which is contains a delta "∆" and a t.
For visualisation purposes i use Matlab Live Script.

Combining several latin letters is easy done by:

```
sym('dt')
```

[image: dt2]

But these either result in an exception or don't do a conversion:

```
sym('Delta t')
sym('Deltat')
```

The workaround to multiply two symbols does not work in all cases:

```
sym('Delta')*sym('t')
```

[image: deltat]

```
(sym('Delta')*sym('t'))^2
```

[image: delta2t2]

However, if i square the symbol, i'd like to have this behavior:

```
sym('dt')^2
```

[image: dt2]

But it should contain the delta symbol:

[image: deltat2]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, you cant use non-ASCII for variables in MATLAB. This means no \Delta, no \epsilon, or any other non-standard chars.

You can generate the LaTeX representation of the results, and then print them either in text in MATLAB or in your favourite LaTeX editor with the function [`latex`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.latex.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
title('\Deltat')
```

[image]

If you want, you can also do

```
title('\Deltat^{2}')
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to use this symbol in calculations. Therfore, i need an object of class 'sym'. I think this is part of the symbolic-math-toolbox. So this title syntax does not help.

Comment: `sym` is not accepting `latex` symbols, therefore I don't think you can do it.

Comment: I'm not sure because it is possible to generate a delta symbol using sym('Delta').

Comment: If you find it, do explain it to me too,  good luck, hope you find it.

Comment: @checkThisOut MATLAB only accepts ASCII as variable names and such, so the answer is no, you can not use Delta, nor epsilon, nor other non ASCII character for code. You can use it for text, but not variables.

Comment: Well, at least we tried. Maybe one day you use my code for your plot titles :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [char function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) to display ascii characters based on their [unicode decimal](https://www.ascii-code.com/character/%CE%94):

```
>> char(916)

ans =

'Δ'
```

Comment: The question is about creating a symbolic math variable that contains the delta character, not just printing it to the console.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood the question.